# Not able to start Ray client server at the second and next executions

Tags: python, ray

I have a Ray cluster deployed on an AKS cluster. Currently I have only 1 worker node.
The version of Ray I'm using is the 1.9.0.

[image: Ray namespace pods]

The pod called `linear-model-5cd66b57d8-rn6ft` contains the code to run the training of a Pytorch model. I got the code from the official documentation: [Ray Pytorch code example](https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-1.9.0/train/examples/train_fashion_mnist_example.html).

I'm trying to connect to the Ray cluster using

`ray.init(address="ray://10.0.210.159:10001", runtime_env=ray_env)`

where `10.0.210.159` is the IP address of the Kubernetes service that creates Ray automatically installing it using the helm chart.

`ray_env` contains some needed Python modules:

```
ray_env = {"conda": {"dependencies": ["pytorch", "torchvision", "pip", {"pip": ["numpy"]}]}}
```

Now, the first time that the pod has been scheduled, all worked fine (Pytorch model trained), but in the second and in the next executions I got the following error:

[image]

Does someone know why I get this error?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm getting this error:

[image: Conda error]

Something wrong with Conda or pip.